# Is the song name "U and I" supposed to be Ui's name?

Tags: k-on

In Episode 17 of Season 2 *No Club Room*, when Ui is sick, she wakes up and looks at the lyrics Yui wrote. I am watching the English-dubbed version and on the top of the paper the song is titled "*U and I*".

English-wise, this looks like Ui's name if written in Romaji and it makes sense given that Yui wrote it when she was caring for Ui, a time in Yui's life where she doesn't have Ui looking after her like she usually does.

So I am wondering, in the Japanese version, is this song supposed to just be Ui's name?

Comment: AFAIK, by the context and the lyrics, yes. I'll write an answer when I get my computer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you mean when you ask whether the song is "supposed to be" Ui's name, but the following things are true:

- The title of the song is the same in Japanese ("U&I").
- A Japanese listener would certainly recognize this as the two letters in the romanization of Ui's name.
- It is also likely that a Japanese listener would also recognize these as meaning "you" and "I" (as in "me"). (Compare: [You wa Shock!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U9s8C6qnLQk#t=34s))
- Hence, I claim that this wordplay is clearly intentional, and that Japanese listeners would recognize this.
- The song is quite explicitly "from" Yui "to" Ui. I don't know whether the dub translates the songs, but in essence, the lyrics are all about Yui saying how she needs Ui to be there for her, and how thankful she is for Ui being in her life.

Hopefully this answers your question.